# Import to MongoLabs DB service hosted on Bluemix

Tags: mongodb, ibm-cloud

Looking for a way to import data from the command line.  I have a MongoLab DB in the IBM Bluemix environment, and I want to import data into the DB.  I have installed the MongoDB server package, so I have access to the mongoimport command.  i am expecting to issue a command that looks like this:

mongoimport --h hostname_on_IBM_Bluemix --db calendar --collection users --file users.json --jsonArray

Is this possible?  How do I determine the hostname in the Bluemix environment?

Answer (score 1):

When connecting to your instance of MongoLab on Bluemix, you are actually just talking to an account on MongoLab that Bluemix interfaces with. Bluemix does not host the data - MongoLab does and talks to Bluemix. Click on the MongoLab service in Bluemix and you will see the button that opens the MongoLab website.

Your best bet for accomplishing this is one of the many methods documented in the [MongoLab documentation on migrating data](http://docs.mongolab.com/migrating/). Create your 2nd instance of a MongoLab in Bluemix and interface between them using the MongoLab methods - included in those methods is the command line interface you can use.

I hope this makes sense - if not, comment below. Thanks